# CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") method is not returning first key into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, outlook

I am struggling to figure out why my code is not working correctly. The goal here is to make an array of all the people who have outstanding items that need to be addressed. There is a named table Accounts_Receivable, that has a column Address (boolean). If a person has a TRUE value in the Address column they should receive an email. The getEmails function works correctly and outputs a two-dimensional array with the person's name and email that is found in Outlook.

Here is how I have the code working:

1. Filter the table based on the Address column and Pull Date column.
2. Capture the range of visible cells into the filterRange
3. For each cell in filterRange add its value to the tblArr array.
4. Remove duplicate entries from tblArr with the RemoveDuplicates function output into the filtArr array.
5. Use the getEmails function on the filtArr array to output the emailArr array.

The issue is, when I put the tblArr into the RemoveDuplicates function, the first name in the array is removed and is not included in the filtArr array. I am not sure why the returned array is excluding the first key

Example:

```
tblArry: {Billy, Billy, Billy, Brad, Brad, Lance, Linda, Linda, Mark, Graham, Graham, Graham}
```

is returning

```
filtArr: {Brad, Lance, Linda, Mark, Graham}
```

but should be returning:

```
filtArr: {Billy, Brad, Lance, Linda, Mark, Graham}
```

When I debug.print the uniqueArr array, I do receive the correct output. I am lost after that step of debugging?

```
Sub PrincipalsToEmail()
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim newestDate As Date
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim tblArr() As Variant
    Dim filtArr() As Variant

    'Change "Table1" to the name of your table
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Accounts Receivable").ListObjects("Accounts_Receivable")
    
    'Check if there are any filters applied to the table
    If tbl.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
        'If filters are applied, clear them
        tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
            
    ' Filter the table based on the Address column
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=True
    
    ' Filter the table based on the Pull Date column
    newestDate = WorksheetFunction.Max(tbl.ListColumns(27).DataBodyRange)
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:=">=" & newestDate, Operator:=xlAnd
    
    ' Get the range of visible cells in the data column
    Set filterRange = tbl.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'Define an array with filterRange data
    ReDim tblArr(1 To filterRange.Cells.Count)
    
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In filterRange
        i = i + 1
        tblArr(i) = CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    
    filtArr = RemoveDuplicates(tblArr)
    
    'Call the function to retrieve emails
    emailArr = getEmails(filtArr)

    ' Output the new array in Debug window
    Dim z As Long
    For z = 1 To UBound(tblArr)
            Debug.Print tblArr(z)
    Next z

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To UBound(emailArr, 1)
            Debug.Print emailArr(x, 2)
    Next x

End Sub

Function getEmails(names As Variant) As Variant
    Dim outputArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim outlookNamespace As Object
    Dim outlookRecipient As Object
    Dim outlookAddressList As Object
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set outlookAddressList = outlookNamespace.AddressLists("Global Address List")
    
    ReDim outputArray(1 To UBound(names), 1 To 2)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(names)
        outputArray(i, 1) = names(i)
        
        ' Retrieve the email address for the current name
        Set outlookRecipient = outlookAddressList.AddressEntries(names(i)).GetExchangeUser
        outputArray(i, 2) = outlookRecipient.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Next i
    
    getEmails = outputArray
End Function

Function RemoveDuplicates(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i)) = 1
    Next i
    
    Dim uniqueArr() As Variant
    ReDim uniqueArr(0 To dict.Count - 1)
    
    Dim key As Variant, j As Long
    j = 0
    For Each key In dict.keys
        uniqueArr(j) = key
        j = j + 1
    Next key
    
    RemoveDuplicates = uniqueArr
End Function
```

Comment: No need to use `uniqueArr` and load it by iteration. You can simply use `RemoveDuplicates = Dict.keys`. Which is a zero based array. Then use `For i = 0 To UBound(names)` instead of `For i = 1 To UBound(names)` in `getEmails` function.

Answer (score 1):

The fix to this issue was changing the line ReDim uniqueArr(0 To dict.Count - 1) to ReDim uniqueArr(1 To dict.Count). This will set the lower bound of the array to 1, and the output array will include all the unique values from the input array.

Can't believe I made this mistake. Got to check the bounds!

```
Function RemoveDuplicates(arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i)) = 1
    Next i
    
    Dim uniqueArr() As Variant
    ReDim uniqueArr(1 To dict.Count)
    
    Dim key As Variant, j As Long
    j = 1
    For Each key In dict.keys
        uniqueArr(j) = key
        j = j + 1
    Next key
    
    RemoveDuplicates = uniqueArr

End Function
```